# Specify "subscribers only" privacy level of page post using Meta Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post subscriber only post to the Facebook page using Graph API. I've checked what is the value of [privacy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/privacy/) for such a post created with Meta tools, and it is as follows:

```
"privacy": {
    "allow": "",
    "deny": "",
    "description": "Subscribers only",
    "friends": "",
    "value": "CUSTOM"
  }
```

When I try to recreate such a post, I receive the following error: `(#100) privacy parameters must be specified if value is 'CUSTOM'.`

So it seems like it's not possible at all, as FB expects one to list all the users needed (i.e. page subscribers) in the `allow`, and due to their security/privacy setup one can't access that data... right? I really hope I'm missing something available, like specific value for `friends` or anything like that.